# How to make Firefox, NOT cache my webpage

Tags: php, javascript, caching, cache-control

I have this page, let's call it `index.php`

`index.php` has a list of users and a remove user button. That will take them to `removeUser.php`

And the last line of `removeUser.php` is to go back to `index.php`

But in Firefox, it still looks the same, a normal user won't know how to do a hard-refresh or clear the cache every time the page loads manually.

I have tried

```
CACHE-CONTROL NO-CACHE,NO-STORE
```

and also

```
PRAGMA NO-CACHE,NO-STORE
```

I even tried setting `EXPIRY 0` in the META tags, none of these help. Although it all works perfectly in Chrome and other browsers, it's just Firefox that has this problem.

These are my headers, requested by @alex

```
http://localhost/xChange/home.php

GET /xChange/home.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.10) Gecko/20100914 Firefox/3.6.10
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://localhost/xChange/home.php
Cookie: laobgcidne=yes; eambacidle=inaresh.online@gmail.com
Cache-Control: max-age=0

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 10 Dec 2010 08:28:25 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.0
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 6130
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html
```

Comment: The problem could be that you still have item in cache. clear cache and try again? P.S: you don't have etag, last-modified headers also!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Send a expires header for a date in the past.

#### Example

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

#### Update

Your headers look pretty good. I don't know what Firefox is doing.

You could do this on the link, to make sure it always downloads a fresh copy.

```
<?php $link = 'home.php'; ?>
<a href="<?php echo $link . '?m=' . filemtime($link); ?>">Home</a>
```

Comment: I tried it, and I also tried it with META tags, they don't work.

Comment: @Nareshkumar Rao Can you confirm the headers are being sent? Check with [LiveHTTPHeaders](http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org/). Don't use `meta` tags, these headers need to be sent before the browser starts parsing the request body.

Answer (score 3):

- First maybe your `curl --head
  index.php` summary could help us.
- This explains caching in full detail:
  http://www.mozilla.org/projects/netlib/http/http-caching-faq.html.
- use
  http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
  to set headers.
- Also have look at `Etag,
  If-None-Match, Last-Modified,
  if-modified-since`
- Or if it really does not work you
  could timestamp your urls

  `index.php?<?= echo time(); ?>`

Comment: I have added my headers to the question as you requested.

Answer (score 1):

Simply Press Ctrl+F5 for hard refresh on your browser page it removes Cache of current page and load the newly Edited Page